# VBA - Find the corresponding column of a given header/string in a particular row & workbook

Tags: vba, excel

My excelsheet is such:
[image]

As seen, Row 1 is the column headers (ITEM, PART NUMBER, ATA 2 ..)
Using VBA, How do I find the corresponding column in which a specific header is present (In Row 1)?

Example:

ITEM. is in Column A, so it should return 'A'

MTBR is in Column L, so it should return 'L'

The intent of this is to automate copy of particular columns from one spreadsheet to another. The current code is:

```
If Form.ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then
        Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns("B")
        Set targetColumn = Workbooks("B.xlsm").ActiveSheet.Columns("A")
        sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=targetColumn
End If
```

As seen above, I am manually giving the column name. I want that the particular column is found after matching the text in `Form.ComboBox2.Value` in `wb.Worksheets(cmb)`

How do I search for the string in `Form.ComboBox2.Value` in Row 1 of `wb.Worksheets(cmb)` and return its column number that I can plug here `Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns("B")`

Comment: Actually, Column A appears to be "***ITEM.***", not "***ITEM***".  Do you still want it to match?

Comment: You would use `Find()` or possible `Match()` for this - have you tried anything?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Oh no then. It should match "ITEM."

Comment: @TimWilliams I want the matching to happen in a particular workbook and sheet, how do I do that using match or find?

Answer (score 0):

Untested but should get you started:

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim f, sht As Worksheet, hdr, sourceColumn As Range

    Set sht = Workbooks("B.xlsm").ActiveSheet

    If Form.ComboBox2.Value <> "" Then

        Set sourceColumn = wb.Worksheets(cmb).Columns("B")
        hdr = sourceColumn.Cells(1).Value 'get the source header

        Set f = sht.Rows(1).Find(what:=hdr, lookat:=xlWhole)

        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            sourceColumn.Copy Destination:=f
        Else
            MsgBox "Destination column header '" & hdr & "' not found!"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```